# How to get realtime updates for post edits from the Instagram API when subscribed to a tag?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've subscribed to realtime updates for a specific tag via the Instagram API using this code (as provided in the API docs):

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
   -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
   -F 'object=tag' \
   -F 'aspect=media' \
   -F 'verify_token=MY_SECURITY_TOKEN' \
   -F 'object_id=TAG_NAME' \
   -F 'callback_url=MY_CALLBACK_URL' \
   https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

This is working well, Instagram calls `MY_CALLBACK_URL` whenever there is a new post with the tag `TAG_NAME`.

My callback script fetches and stores all the data from Instagram in my local database so I don't have to fetch everything each time somebody visits my site. The problem is I don't get a notification when a post is edited or deleted, so often times the data in my local DB will be outdated.

To solve that I suppose I could ...

- ... set up a real time subscription for every single post I get (which doesn't sound like a good idea for obvious reasons)
- ... not keep a local copy of the data and instead fetch everything from Instagram every time somebody visits my site (which would probably push the API limits pretty quick)

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bit of a grey area regarding storing data. I setup an identical setup with the real-time API that stored image URL's in a MySQL database.

Then, client-side I use the Jquery ImageLoaded library before showing images on the page to determine if they still exist or not. It's a bit crude but it works.